# Rounding a timestamp to 15 minute intervals in LegacySQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am pulling some data showing average interactions by hour, but I would like to group this so that it shows me average interactions per 15 minute blocks using a timestamp, unfortunately I am restricted to LegacySQL. I've read several solutions for achieving this with StandardSQL, but how could I do it with Legacy?

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT
DAYOFWEEK(meta_recordDate) AS day_num,
HOUR(property_event_ts)+1 AS hour,
IF(page_type = 'transaction',COUNT(transaction_id),0)/4 AS average_interactions,
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE (TIMESTAMP(meta_recordDate) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), -31, 'DAY') AND DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), -1, 'DAY')) 
AND dayofweek(current_date()) = DAYOFWEEK(meta_recordDate)
AND page_type = 'transaction'
GROUP BY page_type,day,hour,day_num
ORDER BY hour
```

My data from this query looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know BigQuery but I know little math... add `FLOOR(MINUTE(property_event_ts) / 15)) * 15` to your select and group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round minutes of a timestamp to 15 minute intervals in LegacySQL - you can use below expressions

```
15 * INTEGER(MINUTE(property_event_ts)/15 + 1)
```

So, add `15 * INTEGER(MINUTE(property_event_ts)/15 + 1) AS mnt` into your `SELECT` list and `mnt` to `GROUP BY` list

Depends on which way you want to round you can potentially remove `+ 1` portion